# Word Question Involving the Definition of the Derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> A skydiver jumps out of a plane from a height of $2200$m. The skydiver's height, $h$ meters above the ground, can be modeled by the function $$s = 2200 - 4.9t^2$$
>
> How fast is the skydiver falling at $t = 4$s?

If the skydiver is approaching a height of $2200$m, I reasoned that I could use the following definition to find the solution $${f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}$$

I entered the function into this definition and got stuck when I got to this$$f'(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} {2200-4.9t^2-9.8th-4.9h^2\over h}$$

**Where can I go from here?** Can I continue with this method or did I make a mistake a few steps back?

### New Solution

[image]

**How does this look?**

Comment: Should the problem say "the skydiver's height, $s$" or should the equation be $h = 2200 - 4.9t^2$?  And if not, you shouldn't use $h$ as the change in $x$ in your difference quotient because it already has a meaning.  Also, why do you need to go back to the limit definition?  Nowhere in the problem does it say to use the limit definition of the derivative so you should just use your differentiation rules.

Comment: @Bye_World The question does read h meters. Good point, I didn't think of that. In what way could I use the differentiation rules?

Comment: How would you find the derivative of $y=2200 - 4.9x^2$?  Would you evaluate a limit or could you do it an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed is the derivative of the distance with respect to time. You used the correct formula to work out the derivative but applied it incorrectly.

So, given the distance $s(t)=2200-4.9t^2$, we have speed $v$ given by:$$v=\frac{ds}{dt}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{s(t+h)-s(t)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(2200-4.9(t+h)^2)-(2200-4.9t^2)}{h}$$$$\therefore v=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{2200-4.9(t^2+2th+h^2)-2200+4.9t^2}{h}$$Hopefully you can complete this from here...

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try again. So why is h approaches infinity?

Comment: Sorry I meant approaches zero - let me correct this...

Comment: Ah, thank-you! Makes sense now...

Comment: Think I've got it.. How does the edit look?

Comment: Looks right to me :) - BTW: I wouldn't use **s** in your answer as they use that symbol to represent the skydivers height in your question. You could instead conclude with "speed=..."