# Limit definition of a derivative in a word problem about a ball/velocity.

Tags: limits, derivatives

I have a few of the problems like the one below to solve this week for homework. If someone could give me some help on this one, it would greatly help in getting me started on knowing how to solve the rest of them. Thanks for any help in advance. Love this site.

> When throwing a softball directly upward from a height of $5$ ft with an initial velocity of $50$ ft/sec, the height of the softball after $t$ seconds is given by $h(t) = -16t^2+50t+5$ (until the ball hits the ground).

A) Using the limit definition of the derivative, find the velocity $h'(t)$.

B) When is $h'(t) > 0$ and when is $h'(t) < 0$?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Because gravity points downwards?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Well that *is* the unit of acceleration, but that doesn't mean the acceleration can't be negative...

Comment: There are so many questions here of the nature "how can I find this derivative using the limit definition?" One that is almost the same as this one is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169672/word-question-involving-the-definition-of-the-derivative -- the answers there should be a pretty good clue how to do this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the definition of the derivative.  It should look something like $$h'(t)=\lim_{u \to 0} \frac {h(t+u)-h(t)}u$$
Plug your $h(t)$ in and evaluate $h'(t)$ from it.